# Programmatically remove global keyboard shortcuts

Tags: linux, gtk

Is it possible to programmatically (gtk specific [or event xcb methods]) to list the global keyboard shortcuts collection?

I want to test if any of them are using the "Print Screen" key and if it is, I want to unset it.

On Ubuntu we see these shortcuts here:

[image]

Other flavors also have global keyboard shortcuts, for instance opensuse:

[image]

Comment: There are no "linux global shortcut keys" or even "GTK specific shortcut keys". There are GNOME shortcut keys, KDE shortcut keys... Ultimately this all translates to X11 grabbed keys, but X11 grabbed keys are not visible to the user, have no description etc. etc.

Comment: Ah very interesting thanks @n.m. !

Comment: Hey @n.m. I changed the question, is it possible to list the collection to see if anyone uses "Pirnt Screen" and if they do is it possible to ungrab that key?

Comment: Read up on gconf (for gnome), play with gconf-editor and gconftool-2.

Comment: Thanks very much will check! :)